# @mui/x-data-grid + RTL + Jest not rendering the table header and body

Tags: material-ui, react-testing-library, mui-datatable, mui-x-data-grid

I'm currently trying to test if my data grid would display a "No rows" message when I pass it an empty array, but unfortunately it seems not to be working.

**My test file:** (I'm mocking the hook being used in the tested component):

```
jest.mock<DefaultExport<() => { arrayData: any[] }>>("./hooks/useListComponent.ts", () => ({
  default: () => ({
    arrayData: [],
  }),
}));
```

**And here's my test logic:**

```
it("should work when arrayData is empty array", async () => {
    const { baseElement } = renderWithTheme(<ListComponent />);

    expect(baseElement).toMatchSnapshot(); // the output is below
  });
});
```

**The component being tested:**

```
const ListComponent = () => {
  const { arrayData } = useListComponent();

  const tableColumns: GridColDef[] = [
    {
      field: "actions",
      type: "actions",
      getActions: () => [
        <GridActionsCellItem icon={<DeleteIcon />} onClick={() => () => {}} label="Delete" showInMenu />,
        <GridActionsCellItem icon={<EditIcon />} onClick={() => {}} label="Edit" showInMenu />,
      ],
      width: 50,
    },
    {
      field: "fieldName",
      headerName: "some header name (I have about 10 of those objects, not putting them here for brevity)",
      width: 125,
    }
  ];

  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        height: "90vh",
        width: "100%",
      }}
    >
      <DataGrid
        getRowId={(row: Alert) => row.someId}
        loading={!arrayData}
        columns={arrayData}
        rows={arrayData || []}
        slots={{
          toolbar: GridToolbar,
        }}
        slotProps={{
          toolbar: {
            showQuickFilter: true,
            quickFilterProps: { debounceMs: 500 },
          },
        }}
        disableRowSelectionOnClick
      />
    </Box>
  );
};
```

**The `renderWithTheme` wrapper:**

```
export const renderWithTheme = (ui: ReactElement) => ({
  ...render(ui, {
    wrapper: ({ children }) => {
      return <ThemeProvider theme={createTheme()}>{children}</ThemeProvider>;
    },
  }),
});
```

**The snapshot output**:

```
// Jest Snapshot v1

exports[`ListComponent should work when arrayData is empty array 1`] = `
<body>
  <div>
    <div
      class="MuiBox-root css-v0ngl"
    >
      <div
        aria-colcount="13"
        aria-multiselectable="false"
        aria-rowcount="2"
        class="MuiDataGrid-root MuiDataGrid-root--densityStandard MuiDataGrid-withBorderColor css-6h1dhi-MuiDataGrid-root"
        role="grid"
      >
        <div
          class="MuiDataGrid-main css-204u17-MuiDataGrid-main"
        >
          <div
            class="MuiDataGrid-columnHeaders MuiDataGrid-withBorderColor css-1iyq7zh-MuiDataGrid-columnHeaders"
            style="min-height: 56px; max-height: 56px; line-height: 56px;"
          >
            <div
              class="MuiDataGrid-columnHeadersInner css-gl260s-MuiDataGrid-columnHeadersInner"
              role="rowgroup"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          class="MuiDataGrid-footerContainer MuiDataGrid-withBorderColor css-wop1k0-MuiDataGrid-footerContainer"
        >
          <div />
          <div
            class="MuiTablePagination-root css-rtrcn9-MuiTablePagination-root"
          >
            <div
              class="MuiToolbar-root MuiToolbar-gutters MuiToolbar-regular MuiTablePagination-toolbar css-78c6dr-MuiToolbar-root-MuiTablePagination-toolbar"
            >
              <div
                class="MuiTablePagination-spacer css-1psng7p-MuiTablePagination-spacer"
              />
              <p
                class="MuiTablePagination-selectLabel css-pdct74-MuiTablePagination-selectLabel"
                id=":r1:"
              >
                Rows per page:
              </p>
              <div
                class="MuiInputBase-root MuiInputBase-colorPrimary css-16c50h-MuiInputBase-root-MuiTablePagination-select"
              >
                <div
                  aria-expanded="false"
                  aria-haspopup="listbox"
                  aria-labelledby=":r1: :r0:"
                  class="MuiSelect-select MuiTablePagination-select MuiSelect-standard MuiInputBase-input css-194a1fa-MuiSelect-select-MuiInputBase-input"
                  id=":r0:"
                  role="button"
                  tabindex="0"
                >
                  100
                </div>
                <input
                  aria-hidden="true"
                  aria-invalid="false"
                  class="MuiSelect-nativeInput css-yf8vq0-MuiSelect-nativeInput"
                  tabindex="-1"
                  value="100"
                />
                <svg
                  aria-hidden="true"
                  class="MuiSvgIcon-root MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeMedium MuiSelect-icon MuiTablePagination-selectIcon MuiSelect-iconStandard css-pqjvzy-MuiSvgIcon-root-MuiSelect-icon"
                  data-testid="ArrowDropDownIcon"
                  focusable="false"
                  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                >
                  <path
                    d="M7 10l5 5 5-5z"
                  />
                </svg>
              </div>
              <p
                class="MuiTablePagination-displayedRows css-levciy-MuiTablePagination-displayedRows"
              >
                1–1 of 1
              </p>
              <div
                class="MuiTablePagination-actions"
              >
                <button
                  aria-label="Go to previous page"
                  class="MuiButtonBase-root Mui-disabled MuiIconButton-root Mui-disabled MuiIconButton-colorInherit MuiIconButton-sizeMedium css-zylse7-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiIconButton-root"
                  disabled=""
                  tabindex="-1"
                  title="Go to previous page"
                  type="button"
                >
                  <svg
                    aria-hidden="true"
                    class="MuiSvgIcon-root MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeMedium css-i4bv87-MuiSvgIcon-root"
                    data-testid="KeyboardArrowLeftIcon"
                    focusable="false"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                  >
                    <path
                      d="M15.41 16.09l-4.58-4.59 4.58-4.59L14 5.5l-6 6 6 6z"
                    />
                  </svg>
                </button>
                <button
                  aria-label="Go to next page"
                  class="MuiButtonBase-root Mui-disabled MuiIconButton-root Mui-disabled MuiIconButton-colorInherit MuiIconButton-sizeMedium css-zylse7-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiIconButton-root"
                  disabled=""
                  tabindex="-1"
                  title="Go to next page"
                  type="button"
                >
                  <svg
                    aria-hidden="true"
                    class="MuiSvgIcon-root MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeMedium css-i4bv87-MuiSvgIcon-root"
                    data-testid="KeyboardArrowRightIcon"
                    focusable="false"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                  >
                    <path
                      d="M8.59 16.34l4.58-4.59-4.58-4.59L10 5.75l6 6-6 6z"
                    />
                  </svg>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>;
```

Thanks in advance for your time trying to help me!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve the issue with the following steps (some time has passed since I had this problem and I'm not sure whether you need all of them, but will still list them, because they can help somebody):

1. After rendering your DataGrid, you may need to `await screen.findAllByRole("columnheader");` before continuing with the rest of your test **(can't exactly remember if this one is required because even if I remove it in some of my tests, they still pass)**
2. Without this one, my tests do not pass:

```
let originalWindowResizeObserver: {
    new (callback: ResizeObserverCallback): ResizeObserver;
    prototype: ResizeObserver;
  };

  beforeAll(() => {
    originalWindowResizeObserver = mockResizeObserver().originalWindowResizeObserver;
  });

  afterAll(() => (window.ResizeObserver = originalWindowResizeObserver));
```

The above one is in the test's file. We also have testUtils where we have:

```
export const mockResizeObserver = () => {
  const originalWindowResizeObserver = window.ResizeObserver;

  window.ResizeObserver = class ResizeObserver {
    constructor(private callback: any) {
      this.callback = callback;
    }

    observe(target: Element) {
      setTimeout(() => this.callback([{ target }]), 0);
    }

    unobserve() {}

    disconnect() {}
  };

  return { originalWindowResizeObserver };
};
```

3. We also have a DataGrid wrapper:

```
const CustomDataGrid: React.FC<DataGridProps> = (props) => (
  <DataGrid
    {...{
      sx: {
        // any common styles if you need them
      },
      disableVirtualization: isTestEnvironment ? true : undefined, // the tests fail without this one
      getRowHeight: isTestEnvironment ? undefined : () => "auto", // you may not need this one
      onProcessRowUpdateError: isTestEnvironment ? () => {} : undefined, // you may not need this one either, we just got table validations and for some reason we're having a console error (only while running tests) and this removes it
      ...props,
    }}
  />
);
```